# Why does the same code, which was reading excel in C# not reading excel anymore?

Tags: c#, excel

I am writing a plugin for Revit in `C#` and code was accurately reading the excel cells for a long time. Then to same script I gave path of another excel file, now it's not taking `excel` file, even the first excel file which it was reading for a long time. I don't know why the same script of reading cells from `excel` does not work anymore. i am getting an exception as ; "offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection" because at that line im trying to extract some items from list but actually that list has nothing as it is not taking values from excel You can see the image in the link. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSubm.png)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Autodesk.Revit.DB;
using Autodesk.Revit.UI;
using Autodesk.Revit.Attributes;
using Autodesk.Revit.DB.Structure;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Line = Autodesk.Revit.DB.Line;
using System.IO;

namespace RevitComm
{
    [TransactionAttribute(TransactionMode.Manual)]
    class Boundaries : IExternalCommand
    {
        public Result Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData, ref string message, ElementSet elements)
        {


            //-------------------------------------------------Reading from excel  coordinates-------------------------------------------------------------|

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"D:\Example.xlsx");
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

            //---------------------------------------------------Rows and columns--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
            int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
            int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;

            //--------------------------------------------------Conversion Factor--------------------------------------------------------------------------|                                                 
            double cF = 1 / 0.3048;

            //-------------------------------------- No of entered rows + 1 as rows starts from 2 -------------------------------------------------------|                                         
            int rows = Convert.ToInt32(xlRange.Cells[3, "B"].value2) + 3;


            //---------------------------------------------------Getting Active Revit Document--------------------------------------------------------------|
            UIDocument uidoc = commandData.Application.ActiveUIDocument;
            Document doc = uidoc.Document;


            double z = 0;


            //------------------------------------------- Getting the level on which Wall starts------------------------------------------------------------|
            Level level = new FilteredElementCollector(doc)
                .OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_Levels)
                .WhereElementIsNotElementType()
                .Cast<Level>()
                .First(x => x.Name == "Level 1");

            //------------------------------------------------- Getting level on which Roof to be placed ----------------------------------------------------|
            Level upperlevel = new FilteredElementCollector(doc)
                .OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_Levels)
                .WhereElementIsNotElementType()
                .Cast<Level>()
                .First(x => x.Name == "Level 2");


            //-------------------------------------------------  Roof type  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
            var rooftype = new FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_Roofs)
          .WhereElementIsElementType().Cast<RoofType>().First(x => x.Name == "Generic - 9\"");




            //------------- Floor type example __________//
            var floorty = new FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_Floors)
         .WhereElementIsElementType().Cast<FloorType>().First(x => x.Name == "OurFloor");




            //----- wall type example

            var wallty = new FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_Walls)
         .WhereElementIsElementType().Cast<WallType>().First(x => x.Name == "JustGeneric");



            //------------------------------------------ List for Points -----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
            List<XYZ> pointStr = new List<XYZ>();


            //----------Start Points------/          
            for (int i = 4; i < rows; i = i + 2)

            {
                XYZ pi = new XYZ(xlRange.Cells[i, "N"].value2 * cF, xlRange.Cells[i, "O"].value2 * cF, z);
                pointStr.Add(pi);

            }


            //----------------End Points ------------/
            List<XYZ> pointEnd = new List<XYZ>();
            for (int i = 5; i <= rows; i = i + 2)

            {
                XYZ pi = new XYZ(xlRange.Cells[i, "N"].value2 * cF, xlRange.Cells[i, "O"].value2 * cF, z);
                pointEnd.Add(pi);

            }




            //-----------------------------------------------------------List for Lines -------------------------------------------------------|


            List<Line> lines = new List<Line>();
            for (int i = 0; i < (rows - 3) / 2; i++)
            {
                XYZ pk = pointStr.ElementAt(i);
                XYZ pj = pointEnd.ElementAt(i);
                Line l = Line.CreateBound(pk, pj);
                lines.Add(l);
            }

            //------------------------------------------------------- List for Curves for walls ------------------------------------------------------|

            List<Curve> curWalls = new List<Curve>();

            for (int i = 0; i < (rows - 3) / 2; i++)
            {
                Line li = lines.ElementAt(i);
                curWalls.Add(li);
            }

            List<Curve> Curvet = curWalls.GetRange(0,4);

            CurveLoop crvloopExE = CurveLoop.Create(Curvet);

            CurveLoop offcrExE = CurveLoop.CreateViaOffset(crvloopExE, 0.5 * cF, new XYZ(0, 0, 1));

            CurveArray curArrExE = new CurveArray();

            foreach (Curve c in offcrExE)
            {
                /// To put the curves to Currve array
                curArrExE.Append(c);

            }




            // ------------------------------------ Start transaction -------------------------------------------------------|
            try
            {

                //return Result.Succeeded;

                using (Transaction trans = new Transaction(doc, "Neus-Haus"))

                {

                    trans.Start();

                    // Creating Walls



                    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)

                        Wall W1 = Wall.Create(doc, curWalls.ElementAt(i), wallty.Id, level.Id, 3 * cF, 0, false, false);
                    }




                   trans.Commit();
                }
                return Result.Succeeded;
            }

            catch (Exception e)

            {
                message = e.Message;
                return Result.Failed;
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't add your code as an image, add it as text so it's easier for us to help you. Therefore please edit your question. Thank you.

Comment: What does `does not work anymore` mean? How does it behave? Does it throw an exception? If yes show us the exception.

Comment: how can i add my code here, there is no option of file uploading

Comment: i can see in locals window in debugging mood by values, its not taking excel and thus  lists are empty going forward

Comment: You can copy paste your code, there is a button to add format to it

Comment: yes i did paste the code, you can see it now

Comment: Great, thanks. Can you be more specific about what's not working? Do you get an error? An exception? On which line? Or no errors but just blank values returned? Can you tell us exactly what you see? Are you testing with old spreadsheets that you've definitely seen work before - is there any chance that the spreadsheet format has changed? Has the version of Revit changed, or the version of Excel you've got installed?

Comment: i am getting an exception as ; "offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection" because at that line im trying to extract some items from list but actually that list has nothing  as it is not taking values from excel. i am getting this exception on line > list<curve> curvet = curwalls.getrange(0,4)

Comment: i changed the spreadsheet and its not working then i tried to give it the old spreadsheet on which previously it was working but now it also dont work there. Revit version is the same and also the excel version is same

Comment: OK, so that means that your rows variable is < 13, i.e. xlRange.Cells[3, "B"].value2 < 10. Can you check that cell, and that you're reading rows correctly from it?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the error you are getting so that other users don't have to read all the comments to find out the error.

Comment: hey rup !! thats exactly my problem... rows gives value as 3 which means its not taking the value from cell [3, B]. On cell [3,B] the value is 18

Comment: I did it @Chris

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the path of the file needs to be modified so that each `'\'` becomes `"\\"` to be compatible with Windows OS.

Comment: i tried bro, but not working. The same code was alright for long time and now its not working

Comment: You don't need to double backslashes in strings that start with `@` (= [verbatim string literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim)), no.

Answer (score 0):

> Then to same script I gave path of another excel file, now it's not taking excel file

Here is probably the key to the problem, while you re not giving us much information ( the code should be published and not as an image, this way is easier for us to test ). Try executing your program as administrator, if you are running it from visual studio then execute your visual studio as admin, you are most likely laking the privileges needed for your program to run. My answer is based on the premises that your code was already working

Comment: i tried to attach the code and copy/paste code but somehow it did not work and thats why attached image.